# What could these letters "S" in red circles mean in a biochemical diagram?

Tags: biochemistry, chemical-biology, structural-biology

What could be the meaning of the red circles with letters **S** in them in the diagram below? I searched in the text but could not find.

From "[Role of TREK-1 in Health and Disease, Focus on the Central Nervous System](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6470294/)", Figure 2:

[image]

Comment: See https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/16006563/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It almost certainly refers to the amino acid (residue) serine. The numbers (300, 333, 351) refer to the residue numbers. The COOH at the end signifies the C-terminus of the protein (subunit).

The black P's next to it are phosphate groups; both protein kinase A and C ("PKA" and "PKC") are involved in control of protein activity precisely via phosphorylation of serine residues in proteins (amongst others).

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_kinase_A
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_kinase_C

Comment: There are some other hints. The letters S and E are on a line that begins with NH2 and ends in COOH. There is no element E, so S is probably no element either. There is a phosphate near the S, and serines (just like threonines and tyrosines) are targets for phosphorylation.